# How does the sharp 4 chord function, aside from the diminished?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, analysis, modes

I was trying out some lydian chord progressions and found that a #iv (sharp 4 minor) chord sounded really nice. How does this chord, or even a major #IV chord (although that may be equivalent to the bV chord), operate in music?

Comment: This question of mine seems greatly related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64464/why-does-the-chord-progression-i-iv-i-sound-acceptable

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "how does (a given chord) operate" is too broad to handle in a single answer. With only a handful of chords, a whooooole lot of music has been created, so it's hard to nail down what any one of those chords does in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

One example with **♯IV** is in James Horner's score for *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*.

One example with **♯iv** is in John Williams' score for *The Raiders of the Lost Ark*.

The two-chord progressions **I - ♯IV** and **i - ♯iv** are among those mentioned in Scott Murphy's video about common two-chord progressions used in film scores:  [How to Imitate a Whole Lot of Hollywood Film Music In Four Easy Steps](https://youtu.be/YSKAt3pmYBs?si=TlA7I6OH52VHEEPN)

He calls them M6M and m6m according to his own particular way of notating, and assigns a mood to each:

**I - ♯IV** is associated with outer space.

**i - ♯iv** is associated with antagonism and danger.

Jump directly to them in the video here:

[M6M or I-♯IV](https://youtu.be/YSKAt3pmYBs?si=6fCnZNZP-LC_vCSD&t=354)

[m6m or i-♯iv](https://youtu.be/YSKAt3pmYBs?si=DR2fiRMDVaEX4JPw&t=532)

I haven't read, much less analyzed actual scores for these works, so the composers may well spell them enharmonically as **♭V** or **♭v**.  (Though ♭v seems less likely as the third would have to be spelled as  with respect to the key signature, e.g. in the key of C: G♭-B-D♭)

Comment: Are you using upper case for major triad, lower case for minor? So, in `C` major, `#IV` is an `F#` major triad and in `C` minor `#iv` is an `F#` minor triad?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yes, I'm using that convention to match the OP.

Answer (score -3):

Quite a few, as ♯4/♭5 as a 7th is sometimes used as a tritone substitution, which can be learnt about in many q/a on this site.

Comment: Tritone substitutions are usually for the V chord, so bII. bV as a tritone substitution doesn't make sense. It would be substituting for the I chord, which I've never seen.

Comment: @Aaron - I was thinking along the lines of it replacing ^17, moving to IV or iv. Would that make sense?

Comment: That's sort of an "it depends" issue. If you think in terms of Nashville notation, there the numbers are literal scale degrees, then sure, ^b5 would make sense as a tritone substitution leading to ^4. In functional harmony terms, though, it wouldn't be a ^b5 anymore; it would be bII/IV.

Comment: @Aaron - yes, I've always had the tendency to think NNS rather than FH, and I bet those others who think like I do would see b5 written in preference to anything else. Somewhat simpler. Vive la difference!