why does V/iii to IV work?
i was writing chords when I came up with this progression:
IV-V-I-V/vi-IV-V-I
i understand why the V/vi-IV works--because there is only a one note difference between vi (which V/vi usually resolves to) and IV.
however, I found that replacing the V/vi with V/iii also works quite well, making the whole progression:
IV-V-I-V/iii-IV-V-I
this makes no sense to me as first of all, the chords V/iii and IV are a tritone apart from eachother, yet still work well in conjunction in this progression.
also, V/iii has very little in common with the 2 main chords that resolve to IV nicely that come to mind, V/IV and V/vi. the only similarity they have is V/iii and V/vi both have the 7th major scale degree.
voice leading withholds some explanation, but the only notes that resolve by a semitone are the root note of V/iii resolving up to the 5 of IV and the 5 of V/iii resolving down to the root of IV
(see notation in C below).

this is the only plausible explanation i can find, does anyone have any other things that could explain this?

V/iii to iv is also iv0/iv to iv, a plagal-type movement. Every movement by fifths (up or down, or tritone) sounds a bit like a diatonic V-I or IV-I in some key (with minor or diminished chords.) This isn't a "why" but an analogy or sorts.

interesting! by iv0 do you mean iv diminished?

I think V/iii is IV/IV. If it were diminished it would just be called vii°

@ToddWilcox sorry, i'm confused. isn't IV/IV the same as bVII?

nevermind actually, i think ttw just put a typo in front of the 'iv', i don't think the '0' means anything, although V/iii is not equivalent to iv/iv either.

No, I meant vii0-iv acts a bit like a cycle of fifths moving backward; it's not functional but iv0/iv would be a possible symbol if it were. Richard Goldman points out that the diminished fifth in the cycle creates "tonality" in some sense. It causes each note to have a separate environment.

@ttw what does '0' represent? im having trouble understanding

The 0 represents a diminished chord. I get lazy and don't use the degree mark (iv°) as it's not in the extended keyboard on my system. I have to go to Windows Character Map. Sorry for the confusion. Aaron's answer explains things better that I did.

Related due to having the same root movement and use of triads: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64464/why-does-the-chord-progression-i-iv-i-sound-acceptable


The first observation to make is that the chord being called V/iii is a half-step down from I: e.g., if I is C major, then "V/iii" is B major.

A second observation, but a subjective one, is to hear the progression "V/iii -> IV" as actually being "bII/bVII -> V/bVII". For example, relative to the key of C major, try playing B major -> F major -> Bb major (or, more precisely, CbM -> FM/A -> BbM). To my ear, this resolves nicely, and notice the chromatically descending bass.

However, instead of resolving to bVII, the V/bVII serves as a pivot chord to get us back to the starting key (V/bVII = IV).



I:     IV  V  I              IV     V  I
bVII:            bII/bVII  V/bVII


If we really want to push the interpretive envelope, then we could call I V/V/bVII and also view it as a pivot chord. Thus we have three chords interpreted in the key of bVII: two predominant chords (V/V and bII) and the dominant (V/bVII) but which never resolve within that key.


I:     IV  V    I                  IV    V  I
bVII:        V/V/bVII  bII/bVII  V/bVII


Jazz people would call this a tritone substitution, right? (bII7 is a tritone sub for V7)

@ToddWilcox Yes, but I hesitated to call it that since the seventh is missing. The heart of tritone subs is that the 3rd and 7th swap rolls. However, I think one could make a perfectly valid case for the "V/iii" chord actually being a tritone sub for the IV chord. In a jazz or pop setting, where the rules are looser, that would be entirely reasonable on its own — no further explanation needed.

Stepwise motion, aka parsimonious voice leading. In this example, would be better blended if B->A, D#->C and F#->F - try it! :D
